# \newunicodechar fails for PRIME only

Tags: beamer, xetex, unicode, newunicodechar

I'm using Beamer with the XeTeX backend and initially I got lots of warnings of the following form:

> [WARNING] Missing character: There is no `∙` in font `[lmmono10-regular]:`!

So I went and added `\newunicodechar` commands for each of them, e.g.

```
\newunicodechar{∙}{\makebox[\fontcharwd\font`a]{$\bullet$}}
```

And they all work, I've got almost 30 lines all similar for various Unicode characters. However, this fails for the unicode PRIME character `′`. Once I add the following line:

```
\newunicodechar{′}{\makebox[\fontcharwd\font`a]{$\prime$}}
```

I start getting the following error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\__um_scanprime_collect:N ...canprime_collect:N #1
                                                  }{\peek_meaning_remove:NTF...
l.277 ...erTok{→} \DataTypeTok{Set} \OtherTok{_}
```

I'm using Beamer via Pandoc if that matters.

Comment: I get no error if `unicode-math` is not used; I get a different error than stated if I load `unicode-math`. Anyway, you should do ``\AtBeginDocument{\newunicodechar{′}{\makebox[\fontcharwd\font`a]{$\prime$}}}``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the error message you're using `unicode-math`.

The problem is that this package assigns a value to the “active `′`” at begin document, thus overriding what your `\newunicodechar` does.

Solution: postpone `\newunicodechar`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\AtBeginDocument{\newunicodechar{′}{\makebox[\fontcharwd\font`a]{$\prime$}}}

\begin{document}

a′

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using `unicode-math` myself, but I guess Pandoc includes it automatically.